# WP all in one wp migration, can't access admin page

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to copy the content and database from one wp webpage to another. I installed a plugin called "all in one wp migration", and in the end I was suppose to save twice the permalink in the settings but it did not let me (some error page: "The application you have accessed is not registered for use with this service."). Now, the content is copied but if I try to access my admin page/dashboard the same error comes out.

Could somebody help me out please with some solution to this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know what type of error is displayed.

So we better understand